# Google api php client - error on loading controller page

Tags: php, codeigniter, google-api-php-client

I have used example from [this](http://www.formget.com/codeigniter-google-oauth-php/) site.

I have just added the credentials and the line:

```
require_once APPPATH . "libraries/google-api-php-client-master/src/Google/autoload.php";
```

in the controller.

It gives the following error :

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'This library
>   must be installed via composer or by downloading the full package. See
>   the instructions at
>   https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client#installation.' in
>   /var/www/html/gauth/application/libraries/google-api-php-client-master/src/Google/autoload.php:14
>   Stack trace: #0
>   /var/www/html/gauth/application/controllers/user_authentication.php(15):
>   require_once() #1 [internal function]: User_Authentication->index() #2
>   /var/www/html/gauth/system/core/CodeIgniter.php(360):
>   call_user_func_array(Array, Array) #3
>   /var/www/html/gauth/index.php(202): require_once('/var/www/html/g...')
>   #4 {main} thrown in /var/www/html/gauth/application/libraries/google-api-php-client-master/src/Google/autoload.php
>   on line 14

Please help, I am doing this for the first time!

Comment: Post code in your question!

Comment: I am not able to, I will have to add space after every line!

Comment: Have you even read **How to Ask**? Leaving 4 spaces before the code formats it as code! It is not a bug.

Answer (score 1):

It is because your project missed the lib `google-api-php-client`,suggest you install it via composer.

#### steps:

- install composer (if you don't have)
- add google-api-php-client lib to your project
- rerun your code

#### steps in command

- `php -r "readfile('https://getcomposer.org/installer');" > composer-setup.php
  php -r "if (hash('SHA384', file_get_contents('composer-setup.php')) === 'fd26ce67e3b237fffd5e5544b45b0d92c41a4afe3e3f778e942e43ce6be197b9cdc7c251dcde6e2a52297ea269370680') { echo 'Installer verified'; } else { echo 'Installer corrupt'; unlink('composer-setup.php'); }"
  php composer-setup.php
  php -r "unlink('composer-setup.php');"`
- `composer require google/apiclient:^2.0.0@RC`

#### reference

- [composer](https://getcomposer.org/download/)
- [google-api-php-client](https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client)

Comment: I have installed the composer. My project directory is /var/www/html/pc  and composer is installed in /home/mohitgarg68 . Could you please elaborate on 'require' command ? Thanks in advance!

Comment: @MohitGarg not the composer, the error message say  can not find your google-api-php-client, have you install it by composer? similarly, the require code is related with the path-you-install-the-google-api-php-client