# API Youtube-->Fatal error: Class 'Google_Service' not found in

Tags: php, html, youtube-api, youtube-data-api, google-client

I'm getting an error in php, when I try to include the google api php client as follow:

```
require_once '\google-api-php-client-master\src\Google\Client.php';
require_once '\google-api-php-client-master\src\Google\Service\youtube.php';
```

Likewise, I try to include autoload.php file as follow:

```
require_once '\google-api-php-client-master\src\Google\autoload.php';
```

But a different error appears:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'This library must be installed via composer or by downloading the full package. See the instructions at https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client#installation

The codes that I am trying to test appear in the following link:

[Https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/php](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/php)

PD: sorry for my bad english

Comment: Well then, first of all, did you install it via composer or download the full package, and did you read the instructions at the provided link?

Comment: I downloaded the full package from this link: https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is more specific to PHP rather than this specific package.

You cannot use a PHP package just by downloading it. You need to install it and you may use any other package manager instead of `composer` as you wish.

You need to `composer install` the package `google/apiclient`.

In short, the file `composer.json` should include the following code snippet:

```
"require": {
    "google/apiclient": "2.0.*",
    "php": ">= 5.6.1"
 }
```

Once you ensure that you have the above snippet, run the following command:

`composer install`

After this, the error should not occur.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

If the full package didn't work, try to use the composer like the suggestion in your error. You can find in this [tutorial](https://www.codementor.io/php/tutorial/composer-install-php-dependency-manager) and this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35519377/google-api-php-client-error-on-loading-controller-page) on how to use composer.